# How to fix download issues for some users using WebClient DownloadFileAsync?

Tags: c#

I created a Windows Form Application in C# that users of my game modification can use to download updates automatically.

The 'Launcher', as I call it, uses WebClient to download the updates. But the first release of the mod is very big (2,7 GB zipped). The launcher works perfect for me and most users, but for some users the extraction of the zip file logs an error where the file is corrupted and not readable.

I searched already on stack, and it is possible that the file might be corrupted or truncated due to bad internet connection. But how do I build in a method that fix that problem?

```cs
//Start downloading file
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new 
    AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new 
    DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.dagovaxgames.com/api/downloads/+ patch.path), downloadPath);
}  

private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //install the update
     InstallUpdate();
}

private void InstallUpdate()
{
      var file = currentPatchPath;
      //get the size of the zip file
      fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
      _fileSize = fileInfo.Length;

      installBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
      installBackgroundWorker.DoWork += ExtractFile_DoWork;

      installBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += ExtractFile_ProgressChanged;
      installBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += ExtractFile_RunWorkerCompleted;
      installBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
      installBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

EDIT, just showing install code so that you know I am using a backgroundworker to extract the zip.

Comment: You would perform a check - ie did the ZIP file extract successfully? If not, restart the download and try again...

Comment: Yes that would be a good fix, if there were no users from really bad internet connection countries. If the download took 2 hours to complete, there is a big change that the file is corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using a combination of a BackgroundWorker and downloading in small chunks (following up mtkachenko's solution). It also checks if the length of the downloaded file is the same as the one on the server. Using that, it can continue the download where the connection was interupted.

```cs
private void DownloadPatch(Patch patch){
    //using background worker now!
    downloadBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    downloadBackgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) => DownloadFile_DoWork(sender, e, patch);
    downloadBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += DownloadFile_ProgressChanged;
    downloadBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += DownloadFile_RunWorkerCompleted;
    downloadBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    downloadBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DownloadFile_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, Patch patch)
{
    string startupPath = Application.StartupPath;
    string downloadPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, patch.path);

    string path = ("http://www.dagovaxgames.com/api/downloads/" + patch.path);

    long iFileSize = 0;
    int iBufferSize = 1024;
    iBufferSize *= 1000;
    long iExistLen = 0;
    System.IO.FileStream saveFileStream;

    // Check if file exists. If true, then check amount of bytes
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(downloadPath))
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo fINfo =
           new System.IO.FileInfo(downloadPath);
        iExistLen = fINfo.Length;
    }
    if (iExistLen > 0)
        saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(downloadPath,
          System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
          System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    else
        saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(downloadPath,
          System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
          System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwRq;
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwRes;
    hwRq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(path);
    hwRq.AddRange((int)iExistLen);
    System.IO.Stream smRespStream;
    hwRes = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)hwRq.GetResponse();
    smRespStream = hwRes.GetResponseStream();

    iFileSize = hwRes.ContentLength;

    //using webclient to receive file size
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenRead(path);
    long totalSizeBytes = Convert.ToInt64(webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);

    int iByteSize;
    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];

    while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        if (stopDownloadWorker == true)
        {
            autoDownloadReset.WaitOne();
        }

        saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);

        long downloadedBytes = new System.IO.FileInfo(downloadPath).Length;

        // Report progress, hint: sender is your worker
        int percentage = Convert.ToInt32(100.0 / totalSizeBytes * downloadedBytes);

        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(percentage, null);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I report the progress, so that I have a working progress bar as well.

```cs
private void DownloadFile_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    statusTextLabel.Text = "Downloading updates for version " + currentDownloadingPatch + " (" + e.ProgressPercentage + "%)";
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Common approach here is to download large file in small chunks and put them together on client after completion. Using this approach you can: `1.` run few downloads in parallel and `2.` in case of problem with network you don't have to download entire file again, just download incomplete chunks.

Comment: And how to do that with WebClient? I know it can be done using FileStream and/or WebStream, but how do I get downloaded percentage then?

Comment: @Dagovax You should support range requests https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range on server side: https://www.terrybutler.co.uk/2019/01/08/http-range-requests-in-asp-net-core/ or https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support/

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue many years ago and created a subclass of WebClient that uses the DownloadProgressChanged event and a timer to abort downloads that get hung up and cancels the download smoother than the underlying internet transport layer does. The code also supports a callback to notify the calling code of progress. I found that sufficient to smoothly handle occasional hiccups downloading 1GB-ish files.

The idea of breaking your download into multiple pieces also has merit. You could leverage a library such as [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to both create the chunks and piece them back together (many compression libraries have that feature; I'm personally most familiar with 7-Zip).

Here's the code I wrote. Feel free to use and/or modify in any way that's helpful to you.

```
public class JWebClient : WebClient, IDisposable
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public int TimeUntilFirstByte { get; set; }
    public int TimeBetweenProgressChanges { get; set; }

    public long PreviousBytesReceived { get; private set; }
    public long BytesNotNotified { get; private set; }

    public string Error { get; private set; }
    public bool HasError { get { return Error != null; } }

    private bool firstByteReceived = false;
    private bool success = true;
    private bool cancelDueToError = false;

    private EventWaitHandle asyncWait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Timer abortTimer = null;
    private bool isDisposed = false;

    const long ONE_MB = 1024 * 1024;

    public delegate void PerMbHandler(long totalMb);

    public delegate void TaggedPerMbHandler(string tag, long totalMb);

    public event PerMbHandler NotifyMegabyteIncrement;

    public event TaggedPerMbHandler NotifyTaggedMegabyteIncrement;

    public JWebClient(int timeout = 60000, int timeUntilFirstByte = 30000, int timeBetweenProgressChanges = 15000)
    {
        this.Timeout = timeout;
        this.TimeUntilFirstByte = timeUntilFirstByte;
        this.TimeBetweenProgressChanges = timeBetweenProgressChanges;

        this.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(MyWebClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
        this.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(MyWebClient_DownloadProgressChanged);

        abortTimer = new Timer(AbortDownload, null, TimeUntilFirstByte, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    protected void OnNotifyMegabyteIncrement(long totalMb)
    {
        NotifyMegabyteIncrement?.Invoke(totalMb);
    }

    protected void OnNotifyTaggedMegabyteIncrement(string tag, long totalMb)
    {
        NotifyTaggedMegabyteIncrement?.Invoke(tag, totalMb);
    }

    void AbortDownload(object state)
    {
        cancelDueToError = true;
        this.CancelAsync();
        success = false;
        Error = firstByteReceived ? "Download aborted due to >" + TimeBetweenProgressChanges + "ms between progress change updates." : "No data was received in " + TimeUntilFirstByte + "ms";
        asyncWait.Set();
    }

    private object disposeLock = new object();

    void MyWebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cancelDueToError || isDisposed) return;

        long additionalBytesReceived = e.BytesReceived - PreviousBytesReceived;
        PreviousBytesReceived = e.BytesReceived;
        BytesNotNotified += additionalBytesReceived;

        if (BytesNotNotified > ONE_MB)
        {
            OnNotifyMegabyteIncrement(e.BytesReceived);
            OnNotifyTaggedMegabyteIncrement(Tag, e.BytesReceived);
            BytesNotNotified = 0;
        }
        firstByteReceived = true;
        try
        {
            lock (disposeLock)
            {
                if (!isDisposed) abortTimer.Change(TimeBetweenProgressChanges, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) { } // Some strange timing issue causes this to throw now and then
    }

    public string Tag { get; private set; }

    public bool DownloadFileWithEvents(string url, string outputPath, string tag = null)
    {
        Tag = tag;

        asyncWait.Reset();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        this.DownloadFileAsync(uri, outputPath);
        asyncWait.WaitOne();

        return success;
    }



    void MyWebClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) success = false;

        if (cancelDueToError || isDisposed) return;
        asyncWait.Set();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var result = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        result.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        return result;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        lock (disposeLock)
        {
            isDisposed = true;

            if (asyncWait != null) asyncWait.Dispose();
            if (abortTimer != null) abortTimer.Dispose();

            base.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```